# i18n with express.js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, internationalization

I wont to add multiple language support to my Express.js application where I can detect current language with middleware and get corresponding language data from MongoDB.  So maybe someone know useful package which use mongoose for this reason? If not then can you suggest how I can implement this solution mannualy?
I think to add middleware which check `cookie` for current language and get corresponding data from `mongoDB` save it to `express locals` and thes local will be used in jade templates.

Comment: So, what is the question here?

Comment: Sorry, my question is what is the good tool for using i18n with mongoose. If not - how I can implement such middleware mannulaly. I have updated question

Comment: If you have large amount of data you cannot use a middleware or implement or own. Downloading this data(let's say 100k data for some autocomplete area) to local can be really expensive for user (both for internet usage and time) you have to hit database nonetheless.